# In welchem Kontext wird das Wort „dies“ benutzt?

Tags: word-usage

Ich habe gelesen, dass *dies* als Abkürzung von *dieser, dieses, diese* ist. In welchem Kontext sollte man *dies*, und in welchem die anderen Pronomen benutzen?

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dies#German

Comment: For those who voted close, it's clear what is asked. It's asked whether "dies" als Pronomen nicht-neutralen Geschlechts fungieren kann.

Comment: @c.p. Der plötzliche Wechsel von Englisch nach Deutsch im letzten Satz Ihrer Anmerkung hat mich zwar gerade irritiert, aber inhaltlich gebe ich Ihnen recht. ;-)

Comment: Who told you they are synonyms? This is plainly wrong.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Ach so:) Nach „dies” war ja schwer zurück ins Englische.

Answer (score 7):

(Ich nehme einfach einmal an, dass Sie grundsätzlich wissen, was *dies-* bedeutet, und sich die Frage wirklich nur auf den konkreten Unterschied *dieses/dies* bezieht.)

**1. *Dies-* als Demonstrativartikel**

Determinative sind im Deutschen flektierbar. Sie stimmen in Kasus, Numerus und Genus mit dem Nomen, auf das sie sich beziehen, überein. Das gilt auch für den Demonstrativartikel *dies-*, welcher gemäß der [starken Adjektivflexion](http://www.canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adjektiv/Deklinationstyp/Stark.html) dekliniert wird: *Dies**er** Mann ist alt. Dies**es** Auto ist schön. Dies**e** Farbe gefällt mir.*

Es gibt nur eine Besonderheit: Im Nominativ Singular Neutrum und im Akkusativ Singular Neutrum gibt es jeweils eine zweite Form ohne Endung, *dies*. Beispiele (jeweils aus Hegel, Vorlesungen über die Geschichte der Philosophie): (Nominativ:) *Im Bewußtsein gilt **dies Gebot** als Pflicht: "Du sollst nicht töten."* (Akkusativ:) *Wenn ich nicht weiß, was eine Bussole ist, so lasse ich mir **dies Instrument** zeigen und sage, jetzt weiß ich, was eine Bussole ist.* Diese Formen sind aus heutiger Sicht veraltet (Engel 1996: 536). In den beiden Sätzen würde man heute *dieses Gebot* bzw. *dieses Instrument* schreiben.

**2. *Dies-* als Demonstrativpronomen**

Es ist meiner Meinung nach generell hilfreich, zwischen Demonstrativartikeln und Demonstrativpronomen zu unterscheiden. (Leider tun das einige Grammatiken nicht.) Demonstrativartikel stehen immer vor irgendeinem Nomen bzw. einer Nominalphrase (*jenes/das/dasselbe/dieses [schöne] Auto*), Demonstrativpronomen können eigenständig auf ganz unterschiedliche Dinge (Personen, Gegenstände, Sachverhalte) verweisen, auch ohne dass ein konkretes Bezugsnomen anwesend sein müsste. Zu vielen Demonstrativartikeln gibt es pronominale "Pendants".

Wir haben oben schon gesehen, dass *dies-* ein Demonstrativartikel sein kann und der Nominativ/Akkusativ Singular Neutrum heute *dieses* lautet. Das Wort tritt aber auch als Demonstrativpronomen auf. Dafür gilt Folgendes (ähnlich Helbig/Buscha 2001: 229f):

**a)** Wenn es sich auf ein spezifisches Nomen bzw. eine spezifische Nominalphrase bezieht, passt es sich dieser in Numerus und Genus an. Es gilt das oben Geschriebene. Zum Beispiel: *Unser Unternehmen sollte das Gebäude verkaufen. Wir können **dieses** nicht mehr gebrauchen.* (Wiktionary) / Mit "gedachtem" Singular: *In den vergangenen Jahren wurden zahlreiche Krankenhäuser geschlossen. **Dieses** war das erste, das gesprengt wurde.* / [Ein Mann steht neben zwei Autos und sagt:] *Ich habe zwei Autos gekauft. **Dieses** ist rot, jenes ist blau.*

**b)** Wenn es eine verbale Aussage oder einen größeren Sachverhalt zusammenfasst, wird es sehr ähnlich wie *das* gebraucht und tritt meist in seiner endungslosen neutralen Form auf: *Meine Tastatur hat keine Umlaute. **Dies** ist ein Problem.* / *Das Wetter war schlecht. **Dies** war für uns eine Überraschung.* Das ist allerdings nicht zwingend. Es lassen sich - auch heute - zahlreiche Nachweise für die Verwendung von *dieses* finden. [Nach einer langen Geschichte:] ***Dieses** war der erste Streich, doch der zweite folgt sogleich.* (Wilhelm Busch, Max und Moritz, 1865) / *In der Prozeßpause sollen die Verteidiger nun auch komplette Akteneinsicht erhalten können. **Dieses** war bislang nicht möglich, weil den zehn Anwälten zuwenig Kopien der 1500 Seiten zur Verfügung standen.* (Rhein-Zeitung, 04.06.1998) / *Vor dem Gerichtshof der Republik – Court de Justice de la République – sind Nebenkläger nicht zugelassen. **Dieses** war während des Verfahrens in der Öffentlichkeit heftig kritisiert worden.* (Süddeutsche Zeitung, 10.03.1999)

Auf mich - dafür habe ich allerdings keine Belege - wirkt die Verwendung von *dieses* in solchen Fällen gehoben, oft auch etwas hochgestochen. Eine Ausnahme bildet das (idiomatisierte) Paar *dies(es)/jenes* (im Sinne von "manches, einiges"): *Als Heranwachsender vertrat ich gelegentlich die Auffassung, **dieses oder jenes** nicht wirklich wissen oder können zu müssen.* (Neue Zürcher Zeitung, 19.03.2017) Durchaus aber auch: *So regiert an vielen Stellen eine enttäuschende Farblosigkeit: Abende sind «unvergesslich», die Erschöpfung ist «total», ein Streit «furchtbar», **dies oder jenes** erscheint als «zutiefst suspekt», und man wird plötzlich zu einem «anderen Menschen».* (Neue Zürcher Zeitung, 13.06.2013)

**3. Zusammenfassung**

Die endungslose Form *dies* sollte man heute immer dann verwenden, wenn man sich damit nicht direkt auf ein bestimmtes Nomen (eine bestimmte Nominalphrase) bezieht, sondern allgemeiner auf irgendein Geschehen oder einen Sachverhalt verweist.